# How do I globally exclude an error for a certain message with the VS2012 code analysis tool?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, system.diagnostics

I'm currently getting the following messages from the VS2012 code analysis tool:

> CA1709    Identifiers should be cased correctly    In member
>   'Action.ExecuteAction(string, string)',  correct the casing of 'ID' in
>   parameter name 'merchantID'  by changing it to 'Id'.  'Id' is an
>   abbreviation and therefore is not subject to  acronym casing
>   guidelines.

I have this defined in my GlobalSuppressions.cs file:

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage(
    "Microsoft.Naming", 
    "CA1709:IdentifiersShouldBeCasedCorrectly", 
    MessageId = "ID", 
    Scope = "Global")]
```

How can I define a rule that says "ignore this specific spelling (I want ID, not Id) in all files"?

EDIT:  Mike's solution worked, this is what I ended up with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Dictionary>
    <Acronyms>
        <CasingExceptions>
            <Acronym>ID</Acronym>
        </CasingExceptions>
    </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're going to want to do, **I believe**, is add an acronym for `ID` to a custom dictionary and then you'll be able to drop the global suppression. Follow [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx) to do so.

But, in short, here is a snippet pulled from that document that should be what yours looks like a bit ...

```
<Dictionary>
      <Acronyms>
         <CasingExceptions>
            <Acronym>ID</Acronym>   <!-- Identifier -->
            ...
         </CasingExceptions>
         ...
      </Acronyms>
      ...
</Dictionary>
```

... however, if it's not an acronym it's one of those categories.

Comment: This worked great!  As a general rule, there should be a summary of the steps given in a link for an answer, but I'll mark this as correct.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9, I'm glad I could be of assistance, and I honestly felt that because it was a Microsoft link I wouldn't put the steps in for preservation but rather give you an idea of what piece of the document you would want to be in ... I could have placed the steps here though. Thanks!